# Load data from SQL into listbox in HTA (VBscript)

Tags: sql, vbscript, listbox, adodb, hta

I have an HTA (html application) which recieves data from a SQL query, but when I try to paste the results into a listbox it only gives the last record.

```
Dim connect, sql, resultSet, pth, txt
Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connect.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=XXX;trusted_connection=True;" 
    connect.Open

sql = "SELECT [Var0],[Var1],[Var2],[Var3], [Var4], [Var5] FROM [XXX].[dbo].[Table]"
sql = sql & " WHERE [Var3]='" & FieldUser.value & "' and [Var0]='" & YEAR(Date()) & "-" & RIGHT("00"&MONTH(Date()),2) & "-" & RIGHT("00"&DAY(Date()),2) & "'"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY [Var0] desc ,[Var1] desc"

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)

On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do until resultSet.eof 

objOption3.Text = ""

if resultSet(0) <> "" then 

    'msgbox(resultSet(0) & " ~ " & resultSet(1) & " ~ " & resultSet(2) & " ~ " & resultSet(3) & " ~ " & resultSet(4) & " ~ " & resultSet(5))
    objOption3.Text = resultSet(1) & " ~ " & resultSet(3)
    objOption3.Value = resultSet(0) & ";" & resultSet(1) & ";" & resultSet(2) 
    RegListView.Add (objOption3)
end if

  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop


resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing
```

When I uncomment the MsgBox I can see that all records are found, but it only output the last record (it seems to itterate the query correct but only do the Add action when the connection is Closed?)

**How can I make it input all records in the listbox?**

I have tried to change the Add line without succes - I changed to:

```
document.all.RegListView.add(objOption3)
```

I have also tried to output the resultSet as an array - and I can make an msgbox show the records in the array correct but it is not added in the listbox - maybe someone can help me solve it this way?

Inside the connection:

```
dim dbarray
dbarray = resultSet.getrows
```

After the connection is closed:

```
for i=1 to 100

    objOption3.Text = ""
    objOption3.Value = ""
    
if dbarray(0,i) <> "" then
    msgbox (dbarray(1,i) & " ~ " & dbarray(3,i))
    objOption3.Text = dbarray(1,i) & " ~ " & dbarray(3,i)
    objOption3.Value = dbarray(0,i) & ";" & dbarray(1,i) & ";" & dbarray(2,i) 
    RegListView.Add (objOption3)
end if
next
```

I really hope for some help :)

ADDED:
This is the HTML body of the HTA:

```
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<h1>OpgaveTid for <span id="TextUser"></span><span style="padding-left:90px"><input type="button" value="Mindre" id="SendBtnMinimer" style="width: 50px;" onclick="vbscript:Minimeropgavetid()"/></h1>


<tr>
<td>
<label for="FieldSearchOrg">Search Org:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="FieldSearchOrg" name="FieldSearchOrg" onchange="vbscript:FuncSearchOrg()" tabindex="1" size=8>
<input type="button" value="Save" id="SendBtn" onclick="vbscript:SaveAction()" tabindex="3"/>
<input type="button" value="Part" id="SendBtn" onclick="vbscript:SavePartAction()" tabindex="4"/>
<input type="hidden" id="FieldOrgText" name="FieldOrgText" readonly="yes">
<input type="hidden" id="FieldUser" name="FieldUser" readonly="yes">
<input type="hidden" id="FieldUserGroup" name="FieldUserGroup" readonly="yes">
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="OrgListView">Orglist:</label><br>
<select size="28" name="OrgListView" style="width:160" multiple="no" onchange="vbscript:FuncSelectOrg()" tabindex="2"></select><br><br>
<label for="RegListView">My registrations:  (Tryk F5 for at opdatere)</label><br>
<select size="14" name="RegListView" style="width:160" multiple="no" onchange="vbscript:FuncSelectHistReg()"></select><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Edit registration" id="UpdateReg" style="width: 150px;" onclick="vbscript:UpdateReg()"/>
<input type="button" value="Delete registration" id="DeleteReg" style="width: 150px;" onclick="vbscript:DeleteReg()"/><br><br>
</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` to see what is actually erroring. Can you also please [edit] the question so it shows what `RegListView` refers to in the HTML?

Comment: You might want to lookup "SQL Injection". See also https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Lankymart : Removing `On Error Resume Next` did not show any error.
@GeertBellekens : Can you give me a hint on the "SQL Injection"? - I cant find anything that solves my problem

Comment: @NickiRB which is good, when debugging a problem you don't want to be hiding any errors by using `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Your page is wide open to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements instead of stitching together SQL queries. This is not related to your current problem with the listbox.

Comment: @NickiRB Got some weird syntax in the HTML the use of `vbscript:` moniker in an event handler isn't necessary it was mainly used with the `href` attribute of a hyperlink to trigger an event handler from a link. As Geert points out you want to carefully consider SQL Injection which for an HTA isn't a huge concern but still if you allow data to be passed from a field on the HTA directly into the SQL query you can be misused.

Comment: Where are you defining `objOption3`?  Cannot see it in the code.  Moving the code `set objOption3 = ... ` into the loop should fix the overwrite.

Comment: @Flakes the whole things a mess, that’s just one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when you are displaying items from a collection and only the last item is displayed, its probably because the items are getting overwritten and only the last item is shown after the loop.

In your code, the item (objOption) is defined outside the loop and then the text and value are assigned to the same object and added to the select within the loop, ending up with the last option being shown. The error raised is getting suppressed by the on error resume next.

Just create the option inside the loop and then assign the properties and add

```
Do until resultSet.eof 

    if resultSet(0) <> "" then 
        Set objOption = Document.createElement("option")
        objOption.Text = resultSet(1) & " ~ " & resultSet(3)
        objOption.Value = resultSet(0) & ";" & resultSet(1) & ";" & resultSet(2) 
        RegListView.Add (objOption)
    end if

    resultSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed the problem... This is indeed not the best solution - but it solved the problem.

Any suggestions for improvement is welcome.

```
    Set objOption4 = Document.createElement("OPTION")
Dim connect, sql, resultSet, pth, txt

dim dbarray

Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connect.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=XXX;trusted_connection=True;" 
    connect.Open

sql = "SELECT [Var0],[Var1],[Var2],[Var3], [Var4], [Var5] FROM [XXX].[dbo].[Table]"
sql = sql & " WHERE [Var3]='" & FieldUser.value & "' and [Var0]='" & YEAR(Date()) & "-" & RIGHT("00"&MONTH(Date()),2) & "-" & RIGHT("00"&DAY(Date()),2) & "'"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY [Var0] desc ,[Var1] desc"

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)

dbarray = resultSet.getrows

'On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do until resultSet.eof 

objOption4.Text = ""

if resultSet(0) <> "" then 

    'msgbox(resultSet(0) & " ~ " & resultSet(1) & " ~ " & resultSet(2) & " ~ " & resultSet(3) & " ~ " & resultSet(4) & " ~ " & resultSet(5))
    objOption4.Text = resultSet(1) & " ~ " & resultSet(3)
    objOption4.Value = resultSet(0) & ";" & resultSet(1) & ";" & resultSet(2) 
    'RegListView.Add(objOption4)
    'document.all.RegListView.add(objOption4)
end if

  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop


resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing
```

By using the array that I create inside the connection I run 2 loops on the array and the listbox to add the records

> ```
> for i=1 to 100
>   objOption4.Text = ""
>   objOption4.Value = ""   
> if dbarray(1,i) <> "" and dbarray(3,i) <> "LOGON" then
>   'msgbox (dbarray(1,i) & " ~ " & dbarray(3,i))
>   objOption4.Text = dbarray(1,i) & " ~ " & dbarray(3,i)
>   objOption4.Value = dbarray(0,i) & ";" & dbarray(1,i) & ";" & dbarray(2,i) 
>   objOption4.id = i
>   if objOption4.Value <> "" then
>
>       j=0
>       k=0
>       For Each o In Document.getElementById("RegListView").Options
>           if k=0 then
>               if o.text = "" Then
>                   j=j+1
>                   'MsgBox o.Text
>                   o.text = objOption4.Text
>                   o.value = objOption4.Value
>                   k=1
>               End if
>           End if
>       Next
>
>       'msgbox (objOption4.Value)
>       RegListView.Add(objOption4),0+i
>   end if
> end if
> next
> ```

Comment: you could maybe also indicate what you did to actually solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - I have added a part describing the change I made to solve it